# How to link div visibility with input text by simple if condition statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to link the visibility of two html div with whether input has value or not by very simple if condition statement but I may have problem in it.

html:

```
<input id="tags" />
<div id="div1" >
  this is first div means input don't have value values
</div>
<div id="div2" >
  this is second div means input does have value.
</div>
```

---

script:

```
$('#tags').on('keyup',function(e){
    var div1 =  $('#div1');
    var div2 =  $('#div2');
    var txt=$(this).val ;
  if (txt.length == 0){
    div1.hide();
    div2.show();
  } else {
    div1.show();
    div2.hide();
  }  
});
```

---

It works only by the first time I type to input.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error:Invalid jquery Object** change to [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `val` .And validate the length.use with `trim()` for remove the unwanted space  otherwise it will be count the empty spaces also

```js
$('#tags').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  var div2 = $('#div2');
  var txt = $(this).val().trim().length;
  if (txt.length == 0) {
    div1.hide();
    div2.show();
  } else {
    div1.show();
    div2.hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tags" />
<div id="div1">
  this is first div means input don't have value values
</div>
<div id="div2">
  this is second div means input does have value.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
var txt=$(this).val() ;
```

instead of

```
var txt=$(this).val ;
```

Refer jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for correct usage of val() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).val().length`

```
<input id="tags" />
<div id="div1" >
    this is first div means input don't have value values
</div>
<div id="div2" >
    this is second div means input does have value.
</div>


$('#tags').keyup(function() {

    // If value is not empty
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        div1.hide();
        div2.show();
    } else {
         div1.show();
         div2.hide();
    }
}).keyup(); // Trigger the keyup event on page load
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
        $('#tags').on('keyup',function(e){
            var div1 =  $('#div1');
            var div2 =  $('#div2');
            var txt=$(this).val() ;
            if (!txt.length){
                div1.show();
                div2.hide();

            } else {
                div1.hide();
                div2.show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declaring outside of the functions speeds up the page because it prevents 
// jQuery from parsing the hole html document again.
var div1 = $('#div1');
var div2 = $('#div2');

// Declare the function outside of jQuery so that we can init the fields
function handleKeyup(event) {
    var content = event.target.value;

    if (content.length !== 0) {
        div1.hide();
        div2.show();
        return;
    }

    div1.show();
    div2.hide();
}

// Call the function with no data to init the div fields
handleKeyup({ target: { value: '' } });

// Register the keyup listener
$('#tags').on('keyup', handleKeyup);
```

Hope it helps. Here's a pen of the working code: https://codepen.io/flasd/pen/mMXYMa